# Mostrar un video diferente al hacer click con javascript en un enlace generado por php

Tags: javascript

Este es un trozo de una web que estoy haciendo. Esta tabla muestra una serie de ejercicios de un gimnasio y, en cada una de las filas de la tabla, además de los atributos básicos hay un link a un vídeo que se muestra al hacer clic en el glyphicon vídeo.

El problema es que no sé cómo hacer para que el vídeo que se muestre sea en concreto el de la túpla en la que estoy haciendo clic. No sé cómo enviarle al iframe el enlace para insertar en el data src según se haga clic en uno o en otro, ya que siempre muestra el mismo vídeo.

Dejo una imagen de la página en concreto por si sirve de ayuda:

[image]

```
<script>
function postYourAdd () 
{
    var iframe = $("#forPostyouradd");
    iframe.attr("src", iframe.data("src")); 
}
</script>

<table class="default">
<!-- Listar Ejercicios -->
<?php 
foreach ($arrayEjercicio as $ejer)  
{
?>

    <tr>                                                        
        <td width='15%'> <?php echo $ejer['nombreejercicio'] ?> </td>
        <td width='15%'> <?php echo $ejer['tipoejercicio'] ?> </td>
        <td width='15%'> <?php echo $ejer['niveldificultad'] ?> </td>
        <td width='10%'><div id="<?php echo $ejer['video']?>
            "onclick="postYourAdd()"  class='glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle'></td>
        <td width='12%'><a class="icon-edit" href="e_detalles_ejer.php?ejer=
            <?php echo $ejer['idejercicio']?>"> <div class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'>
            </div></a></td>
        <td width='12%'><a class="icon-trash" href="e_del_ejer.php?ejer=
            <?php echo $ejer['idejercicio']?>"> <div class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'>
            </div></a></td>
    </tr>

<?php
}
?>
</table>
<table class='alternative'>
    <tr>
        <td width='25%'></td>
        <td width='15%' colspan='4'><div class='button'><a href="e_nuevo_ejer.php"
            class="boton"><?php echo $idioma['nuevo_ejer'];?></a></div></td>
        <td width='25%'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class='alternative'>
<tr>
    <td width='33%'></td>
    <td widht='60%'><iframe id="<?php echo $ejer['video']?>" data-src="
    <?php echo $ejer['video']?>" src="about:blank" width="420" height="315" 
        style="background:#E0F0F0"></iframe></td>    
    <td width='25%'></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer las siguientes modificaciones.

- En el `script` que muestra el video, podrías recibir por parámetro la `URL` del video, así:

  ```
  function postYourAdd (video) {
    $("#forPostyouradd").attr("src", video); 
  }
  ```
- En el `glyphicon video` deberías pasar la `URL` al video directamente a la función, así:

  ```
  <div onclick="postYourAdd('<?php echo $ejer['video']?>')" 
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></div>
  ```
- Y por ultimo tu `iframe` deberia tener el `id="forPostyouradd"`, así:

  ```
  <iframe id="forPostyouradd" src="about:blank" width="420" height="315" 
  style="background:#E0F0F0"></iframe>
  ```

Comment: Antes de nada gracias por tu ayuda Marcos. He probado exactamente lo que me dices pero no se visualiza ningun video. Creo que me falta recoger la variable que paso por click en el iframe aunque no estoy seguro

Comment: @Edgard, ¿te serviría que en mi respuesta incluya todo el código que esta en tu pregunta incluyendo las modificaciones sugeridas?